# Не могу получить ответ на GET запрос используя технологию spring-boot-starter-data-rest

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

В спринге я довольно зеленый и начал его изучать сравнительно недавно.
Я создавал rest приложение на примере простой таблицы с одним ключом (3 столбца в таблице) и все прекрасно работало.
Решил попробовать что-то сложнее и тут сел.
Проблема в том, что компилятор все запускает и ошибок никаких нет и теперь не понимаю в какую сторону копать.

У меня есть база MySQL с одной таблицей:
SELECT * FROM logicgp_mp.price_m1;

[image: Скрин базы]

Я создал stringboot приложение где есть

1. Реализация объекта из базы

```
package ru.dmitriirikhter.shop.mcpanel.entity;

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;
import ru.dmitriirikhter.shop.mcpanel.entity.primarykey.M1PrimaryKey;

import javax.persistence.*;

@ToString
@Entity
@Table(name = "price_m1")
@IdClass(M1PrimaryKey.class)
public class M1Offer {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "name")
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String name;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "product_id")
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private int product_id;
    @Column(name = "info")
    @Getter
    @Setter
    String info;
    @Column(name = "top")
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private boolean top;
    @Column(name = "img")
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String img;
    @Column(name = "currency")
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String currency;
    @Column(name = "price")
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private int price;
    @Column(name = "price_high")
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private int price_high;
    @Column(name = "pay")
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private float pay;
    @Column(name = "geo_name")
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String geo_name;
    @Column(name = "callm1")
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private boolean callm1;
    @Column(name = "code")
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String code;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "shop")
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String shop;
    @Column(name = "available")
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String available;
    @Column(name = "add_date")
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String add_date;
    @Column(name = "offer_lock")
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private boolean offer_lock;

    public M1Offer(int id, String name, int product_id, String info, boolean top, String img, String currency, int price, int price_high, float pay, String geo_name, boolean callm1, String code, String shop, String available, String add_date, boolean offer_lock) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.product_id = product_id;
        this.info = info;
        this.top = top;
        this.img = img;
        this.currency = currency;
        this.price = price;
        this.price_high = price_high;
        this.pay = pay;
        this.geo_name = geo_name;
        this.callm1 = callm1;
        this.code = code;
        this.shop = shop;
        this.available = available;
        this.add_date = add_date;
        this.offer_lock = offer_lock;
    }


    public M1Offer() {

    }
}
```

так же создал клас составного ключа:

```
package ru.dmitriirikhter.shop.mcpanel.entity.primarykey;


import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;

import java.io.Serializable;


@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString
public class M1PrimaryKey implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private int id;
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private int product_id;
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String shop;

    public M1PrimaryKey() {
    }

    public M1PrimaryKey(int id, int product_id, String shop) {
        this.id = id;
        this.product_id = product_id;
        this.shop = shop;
    }
}
```

И создал DAO интерфейс:

```
package ru.dmitriirikhter.shop.mcpanel.dao;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import ru.dmitriirikhter.shop.mcpanel.entity.M1Offer;
import ru.dmitriirikhter.shop.mcpanel.entity.primarykey.M1PrimaryKey;

public interface M1OfferRepository extends JpaRepository<M1Offer, M1PrimaryKey> {
}
```

подключил базу в файле application.properties
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/logicgp_mp?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=bestuser
spring.datasource.password=bestuser

в теории данный код должен автоматически создать rest приложение где по адресу:

http://localhost:8080/m1offers/

Я должен получить все элементы из базы. Но получаю:

Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Sat Jan 15 22:17:29 MSK 2022
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available

На всякий случай вставляю все зависимости из maven:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.22</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: А где контроллер потеряли? И для Entity можно использовать аннотацию `@Data` вместо прописывания всех геттеров и сеттеров, а также `@AllArgsConstructor` и `@NoArgsConstructor`

Comment: @ArchDemon Про `@AllArgsConstructor` спасибо. Про него не знал. А `@Data` создавал только конструктор без аргументов :) По поводу контроллера. У меня реализация идет через JpaRepository<M1Offer, M1PrimaryKey>. Он позволяет полностью отказаться от контроллера, если хочешь реализовать самое простое rest приложение. Стандартные GET, POST, PUT, DELETE запросы формируются автоматически. Есть реализованный пример, но с более простым объектом :)

Comment: @ArchDemon вот выложил рабочий пример https://github.com/richterdg92/spring_data_rest.git

Answer (score 0):

Всем кто потратил время - спасибо. Оказалось, что допустил глупую ошибку по незнанию. Ссылка на GET запрос должна содержать верхний регистр, т.е. такой

http://localhost:8080/m1Offers/